# Convert a bit-string to a char

Tags: c#, string, binary, char

I'm trying to convert a bit-string to ASCII characters by 8 bits (each 8 bits = 1 ASCII char).

```
        public string BitsToChar(string InpS)
        {
            string RetS = "";
            for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < InpS.Length / 8; iCounter++)
                RetS = System.String.Concat(RetS, (char)Convert.ToByte(InpS.Substring(iCounter * 8, 8)), 2);                
            return RetS;
        }
```

It throws a System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.

It's not clear for me how comes that an 8-bit portion of a binary string can be too small or too large for an 8-bit Byte type.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Convert.ToByte() works with 'decimal' representation, not 'binary'; so e.g. "01000000" is treated as "one million" and causes an integer overflow

Comment: I thought that Convert.ToByte(str, 2), which I use, works with binary.

Comment: Is this originally a byte array? That is easy to interpret as ASCII and get a string out of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
    private static Char ConvertToChar(String value) {
      int result = 0;

      foreach (Char ch in value)
        result = result * 2 + ch - '0';

      return (Char) result;
    }

    public string BitsToChar(string value) {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return value;

      StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

      for (int i = 0; i < value.Length / 8; ++i)
        Sb.Append(ConvertToChar(value.Substring(8 * i, 8)));

      return Sb.ToString();
    }
```

...

```
   String result = BitsToChar("010000010010000001100010"); // <- "A b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
public string BitsToChar(string InpS)
{
  string RetS = "";
  foreach (char c in InpS)
  {
     RetS = RetS + System.Convert.ToInt32(c);
  }

  return RetS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
    public static string BitsToChar(string bitString)
    {
        var retString = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(bitString, "[01]{8}")) // 8 is size of bits
        {
            retString.Append((Char)Convert.ToByte(match.Value, 2));
        }

        return retString.ToString();
    }
```